# 落ちてしまいました versus 落としてしまいました

Tags: grammar

If I lose my wallet and want to report it to the police officer, what is the correct expression between the two sentences below?

1. 財布**が落ちて**しまいましたが、。。。
2. 財布**を落として**しまいましたが、。。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. is the choice.

Syntactically 1. is not incorrect, but it means your wallet fell in a "spontaneous" fashion, as in "my wallet fell from the night table."

***   Added   ***

Oh, I forgot.

落ちる is intransitive, meaning "to fall."

落とす is transitive, meaning "to drop."

Hence 財布を落としてしまいました = I dropped my wallet (and hence I have lost it.)